# Graphical error while dynamically add views (Linear Layout in this case) in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

How the subject suggests, my goal is to dynamically add a set of views (will be LinearLayout in my case) directly in the ListView loading.

That means that all the work must be done in the ArrayAdapter getView() method.

Here is what I am having now:

**What I would want:**

```
=====================
Text...    
    content of the child's linear layout 1
    content of the child's linear layout 2
    content of the child's linear layout 3
Text...
Text...
=====================
Text...
    content of the child's linear layout 1
Text...
Text...    
=====================
Text...
    content of the child's linear layout 1
    content of the child's linear layout 2
Text...
Text...    
=====================
```

**What I have now:**

```
=====================
Text...    
    content of the child's linear layout 1
    BLANK SPACE
    BLANK SPACE
Text...
Text...
=====================
Text...
    content of the child's linear layout 1
    BLANK SPACE
    BLANK SPACE
Text...
Text...    
=====================
Text...
    content of the child's linear layout 1
    BLANK SPACE
Text...
Text...    
=====================
```

As you would catch the blank space is even added when there is only one LinearLayout to add as children. That sounds very weird.

The following is the code I am using:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView ADI;
    protected TextView date;
    protected TextView vehicleType;
    protected TextView vehiclePlate;
    protected TextView vehicleCountry;
    protected TextView location;
    protected TextView agents;
    protected LinearLayout infractionRootLayout;
    protected List<LinearLayout> infractionLayoutList;
}

public ArchivioViolazioneAdapter(Activity context,
        List<ViolazioneSynchroViolazioneTO> listOfViol) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_archivio_riga, 0, listOfViol);

    this.mContext = context;
    this.listOfViol = listOfViol;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViolazioneSynchroViolazioneTO currentViol = getItem(position);

    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null)
    {
        // Inflates the layout that will be added to root LL
        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_archivio_riga, null);

        // Creates current viewholder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ADI = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_number);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_data);
        viewHolder.vehicleType = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_type);
        viewHolder.vehiclePlate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_plate);
        viewHolder.vehicleCountry = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_country);
        viewHolder.location = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_location);
        viewHolder.agents = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_agent);

        // Dynamic infraction creation
        final LayoutInflater factory = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        viewHolder.infractionLayoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
        viewHolder.infractionRootLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll_viol_archivio_infraction);

        for (ViolazioneSynchroInfrazioniTO infraction : currentViol.getInfrazioni()) {
            LinearLayout infractionView = (LinearLayout) factory.inflate(R.layout.adapter_archivio_infrazione, null);
            TextView article = (TextView) infractionView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_infraction_article);
            TextView comma = (TextView) infractionView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_infraction_comma);
            TextView description = (TextView) infractionView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viol_archivio_infraction_description);

            article.setText(infraction.getArticolo());
            comma.setText(infraction.getComma());
            description.setText(infraction.getDescrizioneInfrazione());
            description.setMaxLines(2);

                            // IMPORTANT STEP
            // Add to list so with rowView.getTag() the populated infraction list of layout will be automatically loaded
            viewHolder.infractionLayoutList.add(infractionView);

            // Add to root view
            viewHolder.infractionRootLayout.addView(infractionView);
        }

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // Sets UI object
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.ADI.setText(currentViol.getIdentificativoADI().toString());      
    holder.date.setText(DateUtils.formatToHumanDate(currentViol.getDataInizio()));
    holder.vehicleType.setText(currentViol.getVeicolo().getTipo());
    holder.vehiclePlate.setText(currentViol.getVeicolo().getTarga());
    holder.vehicleCountry.setText(currentViol.getVeicolo().getNazione());
    holder.location.setText(currentViol.getToponimo());     
    holder.agents.setText(TextUtils.join(", ", currentViol.getListaMatricoleAgenti()));


    return rowView;
}
```

And this is the LinearLayout (**ll_viol_archivio_infraction**) in the Adapter layout I use as anchor for adding the Views dynamically:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_viol_archivio_infraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/iv_violation"
        android:padding="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

edit:
It's not clear why the views have this behaviour. In my logic that would be correct, the view are created the first time the row is created and then they are stored in the rowView itself through **rowView.setTag(viewHolder);**. So when the row must be loaded once more it will retrieve the already populated dynamic with **ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();** and returns it.

edit2:
Added the full adapter layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_viol_archivo_number"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_number_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_viol_archivo_number"
            android:text="@string/viol_bollettari_2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_number_label"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_data"
            android:text="@string/dummy_number"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/dummy_date"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iv_car"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dummy_vehicle_type"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/vehicle_plate_label"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_plate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dummy_vehicle_plate"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/minus_separator"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_vehicle_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dummy_vehicle_country"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_viol_archivio_infraction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iv_violation"
            android:padding="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iv_marker"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_location"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iv_user"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/viol_agent_list"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viol_archivio_agent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_agent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your `adapter_archivio_riga` layout?

Comment: Here it is. Sorry but I was not sure i could post the entire adapter code here.

Comment: So you want to hide the `TextView` when the text is blank?

Comment: No, I would like to show every LinearLayout I dynamically add in the loop **for (ViolazioneSynchroInfrazioniTO infraction : currentViol.getInfrazioni()) {**.
Now only the first item of the list is shown and below it there is much blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by myself.

The solution is very easy and it's just a typo error.

What is needed to do is set the orientation of the root layout used for creating dynamic views to vertical like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_viol_archivio_infraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/iv_violation"
        android:padding="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So the logic I gave to the dynamic creation is **correct**. That's for incite people use my work for their own projects.